# Getting all elements from JSON API response

Tags: java, rest-assured

Getting an API response as below and wanted to get the names for all the fields using restassured.

```
{
    "expand": "projects",
    "projects": [
        {
            "expand": "issuetypes",
            "issuetypes": [
                {
                    "subtask": false,
                    "expand": "fields",
                    "fields": {
                        "summary": {
                            "required": true,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "system": "summary"
                            },
                            "name": "Summary",
                            "hasDefaultValue": false,
                            "operations": [
                                "set"
                            ]
                        },                                               
                        "customfield_10100": {
                            "required": false,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "any",
                                "custom": "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-epic-link",
                                "customId": 10100
                            },
                            "name": "Epic Link",
                            "hasDefaultValue": false,
                            "operations": [
                                "set"
                            ]
                        },                        
                        "customfield_10102": {
                            "required": true,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "custom": "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-epic-label",
                                "customId": 10102
                            },
                            "name": "Epic Name",
                            "hasDefaultValue": false,
                            "operations": [
                                "set"
                            ]
                        },
                       }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to get the names using `respStg1.jsonPath().getList("projects.issuetypes.fields.[*].name")`, but getting gpath error. Please help if there is any way to get the name of all the fields under projects.issuetypes.fields.

Comment: what exactly you are expecting ? also is this Json correct ?

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ - use this for validate ur json. it look like above json is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this = `[*].[*].[*].[*].name`
This should work
For future you can use this link to evaluate jsonPath : http://jsonpath.com/

and for jsonPath syntax and wildcards refer this link : https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html